# Fancybox jQuery conflict? NoConflict() issue

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to use jQuery.

I am getting an Uncaught Type Error with my fancybox.
I've worked out that it's to do with two different jQuery libraries clashing but if I remove the second jQuery library, my mobile menu stops working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you including fancybox plugin? What error do you have? Why do you want to include more than one jQuery version?

Comment: Yes I am including the fancybox plugin. When I remove the 2nd jQuery link, Fancybox works correctly but then my offcanvas menu stops working. So I need to find a way for them to both work.

Comment: So try `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });`

Comment: I managed to fix it myself.

Comment: And so, how do you fixed it?

Comment: I hadn't correctly declared the noConflict so by putting var hello1 = $.noConflict(); and then changing $ to hello1, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it myself.

By declaring the noConflict like this fixed the issue.

```
var hello1 = $.noConflict();

hello1(document).ready(function() {
        hello1(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

When You are use CDN Path for jquery then you use https not http.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```